# Parse server on Heroku returns internal server error

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I've just deployed parse server on Heroku as described
in the Parse migration guide, but when I send POST command using POSTMAN
I get internal server error, code 1
Attached images
[image: Heroku settings]

[image: Postman send]

Comment: Are you using 'myAppId' for your X-Parse-Application-Id? Or is that just for the screenshot?

Comment: myAppId, should I change it in settings?

Comment: You should change it in Postman first. That way we can tell if things are working.

Comment: But in heroku settings 
APP_ID is myAppId

Comment: Ok, looks like you will need to login to the parse backend and find your app_id.

Comment: Ok, just added 2 images with both settings and postman